# Installing composer programatically working on vagrant but not on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, composer-php, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working on Ansible playbook. 
When provisioning on a vagrant machine, it goes well, without errors.
Right now I'm on a trouble on the step where composer is installed programatically.

install-composer.sh (This script has been taken from [Composer Page](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-composer-programmatically.md))

```
#!/bin/sh

EXPECTED_SIGNATURE="$(wget -q -O - https://composer.github.io/installer.sig)"
echo $EXPECTED_SIGNATURE;
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
ACTUAL_SIGNATURE="$(php -r "echo hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php');")"
echo $ACTUAL_SIGNATURE; <- Here is empty!

if [ "$EXPECTED_SIGNATURE" != "$ACTUAL_SIGNATURE" ]
then
    >&2 echo 'ERROR: Invalid installer signature'
    rm composer-setup.php
    exit 1
fi

php composer-setup.php --quiet
RESULT=$?
rm composer-setup.php
exit $RESULT
```

The EC2 is a Ubuntu 16.04 instance, on vagrant as well.

Playbook task where i'm getting the error:

```
 - name: Download Composer
      script: scripts/install_composer.sh
      register: composer_setup
      #when: not composer_stat.stat.exists
      tags:
        - deploy
```

And the full error with --verbose:

> TASK [Download Composer] *******************************************************
>   fatal: [18.203.185.87]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "failed": true,
>   "rc": 1, "stderr": "Shared connection to 18.203.185.87 closed.\r\n",
>   "stdout":
>   "a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1\r\n/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566333565.4-174304924088429/install_composer.sh:
>   5:
>   /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566333565.4-174304924088429/install_composer.sh:
>   php: not
>   found\r\n/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566333565.4-174304924088429/install_composer.sh:
>   6:
>   /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566333565.4-174304924088429/install_composer.sh:
>   php: not found\r\n\r\nERROR: Invalid installer signature\r\nrm: cannot
>   remove 'composer-setup.php': No such file or directory\r\n",
>   "stdout_lines":
>   ["**a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1**",
>   "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566333565.4-174304924088429/install_composer.sh:
>   5:
>   /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566333565.4-174304924088429/install_composer.sh:
>   php: not found",
>   "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566333565.4-174304924088429/install_composer.sh:
>   6:
>   /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1566333565.4-174304924088429/install_composer.sh:
>   php: not found", **""**, "ERROR: Invalid installer signature", "rm: cannot
>   remove 'composer-setup.php': No such file or directory"]} changed:
>
> [192.168.33.10] => {"changed": true, "rc": 0, "stderr": "Shared
>   connection to 192.168.33.10 closed.\r\n", "stdout":
>
> "a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1\r\na5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1\r\n",
>   "stdout_lines":
>   ["a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1",
>   "a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1"]}

Any idea why this line is returning empty on ec2?

> `"$(php -r "echo hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php');")"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Trying what Aaron Said, I saw that php was not correctly installed(not installed at all)

I was executing:

```
ansible-playbook ansible/playbook.yml -i ansible/hosts.ini -t deploy --ask-vault-pass --verbose
```

Note the tag deploy, so in here it is suposed that php was installed. All had to do was remove `-t deploy` from my command!

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is that your EC2 instance doesn't have access to the internet. Can you verify this? The verbose logs indicate that the `composer-setup.php` file does not exist when you're trying to hash it. You should try downloading that file using the current `copy()` method, then doing something like:

```sh
TESTSTUFF="$(php -r "echo file_exists('composer-setup.php') ? 'FILE EXISTS' : 'FILE DOES NOT EXIST';")"
echo $TESTSTUFF
```

If the file does not exist, try to download a different file from somewhere, [such as a dummy test file from here](https://www.thinkbroadband.com/download).

All of the signs point to the file not existing, which can caused by an array of issues. But, the most likely are:

- No internet access on EC2 (Can you ping 8.8.8.8?)
- Improper permissions to execute php
- Improper permissions to write to the destination filesystem

Comment: Thanks for replying @Aaron St. Clair! I have tested and yes, I have Internet, I can do pings to outside. But Thanks to that, I have discovered whats going on. It was my fault. Check response.